# bundle install error : character-encodings

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle

I am getting an error while `bundle install`

`$ vi Gemfile`

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'daemons'
gem 'rfeedparser'
```

`$ ruby -v`

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

`$ bundle install --path vendor`

```
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Using addressable (2.2.6) 
Using cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0) 
Installing character-encodings (0.4.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb 
checking for ‘-std=c99’ option to compiler... yes
checking for ‘-finline-functions’ option to compiler... yes
checking for ‘-Wall’ option to compiler... yes
checking for ‘-Wextra’ option to compiler... yes
checking for ‘-Wwrite-strings’ option to compiler... yes
checking for ‘-Waggregate-return’ option to compiler... yes
checking for ‘-Wmissing-prototypes’ option to compiler... yes
checking for ‘-Wmissing-declarations’ option to compiler... yes
checking for ‘-Wnested-externs’ option to compiler... yes
checking for ‘-Wundef’ option to compiler... yes
checking for ‘-Wpointer-arith’ option to compiler... yes
checking for ‘-Wcast-align’ option to compiler... yes
checking for ‘-Werror’ option to compiler... yes
checking for ‘-Winline’ option to compiler... yes
checking for assert.h... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking for stdbool.h... yes
checking for stddef.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wchar.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c rb_utf_chomp.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c rb_utf_internal_bignum.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c rb_utf_upcase.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c rb_utf_to_i.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c rb_utf_insert.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c rb_utf_hex.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c rb_utf_each_char.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c rb_utf_justify.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c properties.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c private.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c rb_utf_normalize.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c rb_utf_collate.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c rb_utf_chop.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c rb_utf_count.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c rb_utf_squeeze.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c rb_utf_reverse.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c rb_utf_downcase.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c break.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c rb_utf_index.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c decompose.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c rb_utf_oct.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c rb_utf_rstrip.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c rb_utf_internal_tr.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c rb_utf_rindex.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c unicode.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c rb_utf_aset.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_ASSERT_H -DHAVE_LIMITS_H -DHAVE_LOCALE_H -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H -DHAVE_STDDEF_H -DHAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_STDIO_H -DHAVE_STDLIB_H -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_WCHAR_H    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -std=c99 -finline-functions -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -Winline  -c rb_utf_tr.c
rb_utf_tr.c: In function ‘tr_trans_do’:
rb_utf_tr.c:107:14: error: variable ‘modified’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors

make: *** [rb_utf_tr.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /home/sayuj/work/mobme/vas-vodafone-appsuite/cricket-feeder/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/character-encodings-0.4.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/sayuj/work/mobme/vas-vodafone-appsuite/cricket-feeder/vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/character-encodings-0.4.1/ext/encoding/character/utf-8/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing character-encodings (0.4.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install character-encodings -v '0.4.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Can anyone fix this? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Ubuntu 11.10 64bit, try installing

```
sudo apt-get install libxml-parser-ruby
sudo apt-get install expatxxxx
```

(where xxxxx is versions like `-dev` or `--dev` or `1`)

Even if it has not worked try this

```
gem install rfeedparser -- --with-cflags=\"-O2 -pipe -march=native -Wno-unused-but-set-variable\"
```